# Was Russia correct in claiming that Ukraine's NATO membership was imminent given that Ukraine has disputed borders?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, nato

As pointed out in [this Washington Post article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/outlook/2022/02/22/natos-membership-rules-invite-conflict-benefit-putin), before joining NATO all applicant states are required to resolve their territorial conflicts. Given that Ukraine has a disputed territory (Crimea) since 2014, could Ukraine have even joined NATO as Mr. Putin claims?

I think this question was addressed partly from a slightly different angle at [What, if any, reasons prevented Ukraine from joining NATO?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71039/what-if-any-reasons-prevented-ukraine-from-joining-nato) too.

Comment: What do you mean by "imminent"? Also, did Russia say that Ukrainian membership of NATO was imminent?

Comment: I don't quite understand Russia was correct on "what"? Please clearify.

Comment: Ok I think its better phrased as Russia believed that Ukraine was going to join NATO in the near future

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz that doesn't seem like it clarifies the question. How near is near, and did Russia say that Ukraine is about to join NATO in the near future?

Comment: Technically, no. Practically, given how fast does Russian Duma accept pro-presidential laws, and MrP knowing that, he might assume the same could potentially happen on the other side, so either disputed territory would stop being an objection, or say Ukraine would cede Crimea and semi-instantly join NATO on the grounds it has no more disputed territories.

Answer (score 3):

No, it was not imminent. I have followed the events in Ukraine closely and have not seen credible evidence of NATO meetings at which the vote was taken on Ukraine membership and that vote was close. This is a common sense interpretation of imminent. In the same sense as the rain with a probability of 90 percent is considered imminent.

**REFERENCES:**

https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/topics_37750.htm
https://www.nytimes.com/2022/01/13/us/politics/nato-ukraine.amp.html
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine%E2%80%93NATO_relations

Comment: Please post the evidence of such meetings and the results of the vote in the space provided below. I might have missed them, entirely possible… I am really hoping for an objective and friendly discussion! Please bring references as suggested by the [help]. TYIA.